# Export custom javascript file to a Vue component

Tags: javascript, npm, vue.js

I am a beginner in Vue.js and so this question might be duplicate or naive. I want to call functions defined in a custom javascript file within a Vue component. I did something like this.

**custom.js**

```
class API{
    function testCall(){
        alert("test ok");
    }
}

export {API}
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img src="./assets/logo.png">
    <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>
    <testcomponent :on-click="getData">
    </testcomponent>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue';
import TestComponent from './components/TestComponent.vue';
import API from './js/custom.js';

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
    TestComponent,
    API
  },
  methods: {
    getData(){
        const apiObj = new API();
        apiObj.testCall();
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

When I build using `npm run build`, I get below error.

[image]

Any help with this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1:** To define [methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions) in a class you do not need function keyword.

```
class API{
    testCall(){
        alert("test ok");
    }
}
```

**2:** Since you are doing a named export using `export {API}`, your import statement should be

```
import {API} from './js/custom.js';
```

**3:**`components` options is for registering vue components locally. Since `API` is not a vue component remove it from the `components` option.

Comment: One more clarification- some of my functions are using axios for AJAX calls. How do I get access to the external libraries like- axios, jQuery in the custom.js?

Comment: @SouvikGhosh import those modules using `import` statement. For e.g. to use axios import it using `import axios from 'axios'`

Comment: I tried importing it in my custom.js file and also App.vue file but none of them worked and I got build error. Also tried using require("axios") but did not work.

Comment: Never mind. It works. I just had to install axios from npm. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

API is not a Vue component - you should not include it inside the `components` branch. Also, if this is just a bunch of utility functions you can either export them one by one or as a containing object

```
// util.js - individual functions
export function testCall (call) {};
export function testUser (user) {};

// Vue app
import { testCall, testUser } from 'util.js';


// util.js - object group
function testCall (call)
{
}

function testUser (user)
{
}

export default
{
  testCall,
  testUser
}

// Vue app
import API from 'util.js';
```